# Is possible to use Facebook's (Page) Graph API without having an role in that page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

For example, let's say I need to "crawl" (not manually since it looks against Facebook's policies but via graph API) some information from a Facebook's brand page (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/nike/ ).

For example I may need to collect the following fields from a set of brand pages (not just one, such as the one mentioned above, for which I could definitely do it manually), when they are publicly available:
("About tab")
- description
- address
- website
- ...

I was reading Facebook's graph API [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.5) and [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference).

However these permissions are related to **users** and I already worked with that. What I learned it that it works by

> Facebook login --> auth the app to use my data --> the app has access to my data as a Facebook user.

However I'm now interested in **brand pages** for which I found this [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed) and this ([access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens)). However it seems that to be able to use this access token I need to be a user with some role in the page (e.g. admin) and not any user who just liked that page.

So, **is it possible to access brand pages' data (read-only, i.e. GET) via graph API without actually owning/admin/publishing on that page?**

Comment: When a user authorises an app, it gives the app access to make calls on behalf of that user - I think you're getting confused by the parts of the API specifically intended for page owners to use to manage their pages, but any user's token, if they authorise your app, should be able to see public posts on pages (which that user can see, some may be gated geographically, etc)

Comment: so, basically, each brand page should authorize my app to access PUBLIC data which is available even WITHOUT liking the page as a Facebook user?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently no "special" access token is required to access pages' public info.

For example I can create any page (not app) in my Facebook account and then use

> **GET** https://graph.facebook.com/(*1)/feed?access_token=(*2)

- (*1) the page's name (nike) or ID
- (*2)my "bridge" page (i.e. empty page, only used to have an access token. **not** the page I'm using the graph api on)'s access token

Similarly for /posts/ etc.