# How to query Facebook's graph API from an app instead of a page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

Following my question (to which I self-answered): [Is possible to use Facebook's (Page) Graph API without having an role in that page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585461/is-possible-to-use-facebooks-page-graph-api-without-having-an-role-in-that-pa/33586435#33586435)

I would now like to know if I can get an access token for **an app** (created in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) instead of a page (of which I can get an access token in **Graph Explorer**), to query Facebook's graph API?

e.g. with my page's (which is **not** the page I'm querying the graph about) access token:

> **GET** https://graph.facebook.com/24HourFitness/posts?access_token=(*)

(*) access token generated in Graph Explorer (page access tokens) for one of the pages I admin

Answer (score 0):

This is much too broad. It will always depend on *WHAT* you want to query with the App Access Token, because not all object allow using App Access Token, but require a User or Page Access Token...

Refer to the object's docs to see if it's possible for the purpose you desire, e.g.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading

says

> **Permissions**
>
> For pages that are published, you need:
>
> - An app or user access token to view fields from fully public pages.
> - A user access token to view fields from restricted pages that this person is able to view (such as those restrict to certain demographics like location or age, or those only viewable by Page admins).
> - A page access token can also be used to view those restricted fields.